# TypeScript 3 now produces an error with btoa()

Tags: typescript

The code below worked fine until I upgraded to Typescript 3. Why is that?

```
var file = event.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = () => {
   this.fileForUpload.FileName = file.name;
   this.fileForUpload.FileType = file.type;

   var encodedString = btoa(reader.result);

   console.log(encodedString);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Now it throws this error:

```
Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
 Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

What's the fix?

Comment: Which FileReader method are you using to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result), that property can be either of those types, depending on how you read the reader.

Make sure it's actually going to be `string`, then cast it.

Comment: You need to cast it.

Comment: I tried var encodedString = btoa(reader.result).toString(); and still errors